# Android - ExpandableListView isn't showing the groupIndicator icon

Tags: android, icons, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a ExpandableListView in my xml and i'm setting its adapter with a custom BaseExpandableListAdapter.
XML:

```
<ExpandableListView 
     android:id="@+id/expanlist_EstatisticaArsenal"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
     android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
     android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
     android:visibility="gone">         
 </ExpandableListView>
```

`android:visibility="gone"` because i make it visible after some stuff

Adapter custom class:

```
public class Adapter_expanEstatistica extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context c;
    private List<BlocoArsenal> listblocos;
    public Adapter_expanEstatistica(Context ctx, List<BlocoArsenal> listBlocos)
    {
        c = ctx;
        listblocos = listBlocos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View expdanableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estatistica_expanlist_child, null);

        /* Here i populate a tableLayout that exists in expdanableView with some info */

        return expdanableView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listblocos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View expdanableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estatistica_expanlist_parent, null);        
        TextView txt = (TextView) expdanableView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeBloco);
        txt.setText(listblocos.get(groupPosition).getNome());
        return expdanableView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

XML ChildView:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >        
            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tblEstasticaArsenal" >            
            </TableLayout>  
    </LinearLayout>
```

XML ParentView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNomeBloco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="#5E302A"
        android:text="Nome Bloco"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

When i set the adapter of the expanListView and change its visibility to visible, everything goes ok, but it doesn't show the groupIndicator icon. Anyone can help me?

Comment: you use custom view for dispaying group view..
View expdanableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.estatistica_expanlist_parent, null);  
This problem may be due to this view.

Comment: R.layout.estatistica_expanlist_parent is 'XML parentView' code in this post. It just has a textview inside it. I dont know what can be =T

Comment: I tried to follow this link: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/android-expandable-list-example.html

Answer (score 1):

in method getGroupView try use this layout - android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2

as a result, your code will look like this:

```
 @Override
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View theConvertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
    View row = theConvertView;
    TextView textView;

    if(theConvertView == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, null);
        textView = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        row.setTag(textView);
    } else {
        textView = (TextView)theConvertView.getTag();
    }

    //textView.setText();  //TODO set group 

    return row;
}
```

If you can see this method is diferrent from your. I used ViewHolderPatter, read about it (this code work better).

I checked it, in my group mas indicator.

Hope, I help you.

Comment: It didn't work =/ I created a new Android Application and i recreated this code: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/android-expandable-list-example.html Exactly how he says in his tutorial. And it didn't show the group Indicator icon D: - http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/5391/bbhu.png - Maybe a bug in my IDE / Emulator?

Comment: I created a custom groupIndicator icon and, i don't know the reason, but it works. Thanks for the help.